# D7: How to deal with the variables visibility?

Tags: 7

Now I have some variables collected from POST

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $a * $b
```

I need to use them in 2 functions: hook_form() and the callback mail_send() the function that format and sends my email with form elements.

I have implemented the following hooks:

```
function MYMODULE_page() {...}
function MYMODULE_form() {...}
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
mail_send($form_state['values']);
}

//a custom callback mail function call in the submit.
function mail_send($form_values) {}
```

...

Now I don't know where to place those variables to have maximum visibility:

- if I place them in MYMODULE_form() the show up in the form but they are not available in the mail_send().
- if I place them outside everything they are not available inside functions.
- if i place them inside a hook_init() the same as above.

I need a place where all variables are visible. Thanks

Comment: Related and/or dupliate question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/how-to-create-a-module-wide-variable-that-refreshes-every-page-load

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the maximum visibility use **global variables** like below

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
global $c;
$c = $a * $b
```

and you can anywhere like below,

```
function mail_send($form_values) {
  global $c;
  print_r($c);
}
```

There is no special methods exists in drupal, it is just like php.

Comment: Sorry, but I really need to down-vote a suggestion to use global. Use drupal_static instead.

Comment: ohh sorry, i forgot that.But global also a correct suggestion, Please correct me If i am wrong?

Comment: It is absolutely correct, as in "It can solve the problem", yes. It's just that [globals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) are generally considered a really bad idea, and should be avoided if you want your code to hold up to some level of scrutiny.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!. This is best suggestion why don't you add as next answer?