# Simplest way of creating a themed page from a module

Tags: 7, theming

Unifying the questions below, I want to check if the problem and solution is correct:

Problem: I want to create a page with hook_menu from my custom module. This page will have a different template to the other pages. Some of the dynamic content of the page will be retrieved by my custom module.

Solution: the code below, with these convoluted steps:

1. hook_menu with callback function
2. callback function returns empty array.
3. Based on path, hook_preprocess_page retrieves data and send to page.
4. theme suggestion is set, based on path.

**What I don't understand is why 3. and 4. cannot be accessed directly from callback function, avoiding to guess what page we are accesing via path.**

Code:

```
function hook_menu(){
    $items['product-detail'] = array(
       'page callback' => '_hook_product_detail',
       'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
       'access callback' => TRUE,
);

function _hook_product_detail(){
   return array("#markup" => "");
} // function

function hook_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   $cp = current_path();
   $cp_arr = explode("/", $cp);
   if($cp_arr[0] == "product-detail"){
       $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__product_detail';
       // ... get data to populate var1, used in page--product_detail.tpl.php
       $variables["var1"] = $var1;
   } // if

 }
```

Questions unified: [How to Create a single page within a module and set page variables?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177699/create-a-single-page-within-a-module-and-set-page-variables-drupal-7) and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177604/how-can-i-put-the-results-from-my-module-into-a-page-tpl-php

Comment: Error correcction: what must be used is what appears in *bold* after 3 and 4. Direct use of the callback function used in hook_menu.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://www.drupal.org/node/223440?

Comment: Yes, assignament *$variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page__product_detail';* could be used in template.php. I have working sites using the approach. I just want to make it work from the module file, and from the hook_menu or a callback function used by it. It is the logical approach, and I must be missing something very simple or just Drupal makes convolute what could be enormously simple. It is the part *$cp = current_path(); $cp_arr = explode("/", $cp);* what seems terribly wrong, even if it works.

Comment: In template.php approach, I use a dummy node of a specific content type, and use node->nid to put the logic of data retrieval, theme_suggestion, etc. That seems weird, also, even if it works. I will have to strip a module to see how they get it.

Comment: It is not the logical approach, at the module level Drupal has no (very little) knowledge of the theme, it's too early in the page cycle. You want to override a theme template (page.tpl.php) with an alternative, therefore your override happens in the theme

Comment: However, the override works in the module level. It is working now. I moved from template.php to the module, with hook_preprocess_page. Probably you refer to hook_menu and its associated page callback function... but then, the reply to my question is that my method is just one of the few to be used. Let's summarize: I want to create a new page from the module, and I want to load page variables. **Forget about the theme_suggestion.** How can I load these variables inside the callback function? I tried returning an array with key $variables, used theme, and I was not able to make it work.

Comment: OK let's try a different track, have you tried [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context)? Rather than constructing your own version in a custom module, Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for different portions of your site. You can specify a path for the condition `product-detail` and then a template suggestion for the reaction `page__product_detail`

Comment: Yes, I know about Context. Too high-level, I wanted to manage the issue at low-level. The problem is not to have it working (**I have!**) but the problem is that reflects either an almost negligible understanding of Drupal from my part or that Drupal is ill-conceived.

Comment: Why is it too high-level? Context is a standard module on all my sites, nearly 200,000 sites have it installed, on more complex sites I have 20+ contexts defined. Drupal is far from ill-conceived so your statement must be true.

Comment: Well, then with an almost negligible understanding of Drupal I have managed to get a multidomain / multilanguage complex site, which is conceived as a difficult task in Drupal. I do not discard my statement being true, but will look into the inners of a module which creates pages to see how they manage.

Comment: Please avoid asking three questions about the same topic in rapid succession. Take your time to try find the solution, and to write a comprensible question. It's not that you ask a new question for every new detail you find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add variables from the page callback. I imagine the placement of the variable in your `$vars` will depend on your theme.

This works for me using a responsive_bartik sub theme and panels. The `my_var` exists in `$vars['page']['content']['system_main']['my_var']`.

```
my_module_menu() {
  $items['test-empty'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'my_module_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array('This is my var'),
    'theme callback' => 'my_module_theme',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}

my_module_page_view($var) {
  $output['#markup'] = 'Your markup or just an $output render array';
  $output['my_var'] = $var;
  return $output;
}

my_module_theme() {
  return your_theme
}

my_module_page_preprocess($vars) {
  dpm($vars);
  // Path to my_var may differ from theme to theme and by set up.
  $vars['page_level_var'] = $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['my_var'];
}
```

Now your $page_level_var should be available in your tpl.

You shouldn't need the theme callback but I could be wrong. (It would have been a pain not to use it with my current set up.)

Comment: That is what I needed -- the location of the variable value. Instead of being directly accesible via $myvar in the page.tpl.php, it is "buried" in page-->content-->system_main-->myvar. Thanks!!!